# Angular Service lose value after success ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, onsen-ui

What is wrong with this code?
The var "acc" is losing value if used out of ajax success function.
The "AppendUser" method just make a push in object user.
It worked fine in entire project, but in this case it is losing value. Why?

```
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { user_id: user_id },
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(user) {
      UserService.resetUser();
      UserService.appendUser(
                            user[0].user_id,
                            user[0].firstname
                            );

    }
  });
    acc = UserService.getUser();
    console.log(acc);
```

EDIT:
It seems that the problem is using the service inside the same controller that it appends values. If i append value in this controller and get values inside another, it works. But I if try to get the values appended in the same controller, It returns empty object. Why?

Comment: Why are you using ajax with angular. You can use  $http service...

Comment: What type of request it is and why are u using ajax at first place? Easiest way is $http service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Hi, i am new in AngularJS. As I am using angular+jquery I used ajax. The request is OK. if I user getUser() method inside success function, it get's the data fine. But outside it is losing value. Someone know why? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using $.ajax you can use angular built in $http service here's the **[link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)** of official document

```
// Simple POST request example (passing data) :
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

for your application you can use something like this on service

```
var deffered = $q.defer();
$http.get(url,{ params: {user_id: user_id } })
    .success(deffered.resolve).error(deffered.reject);
return deffered.promise;
```

Comment: My problem is not request. The request is returning the correct data. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: but your implementation is not the best angular way. `The purpose of the deferred object is to expose the associated Promise instance as well as APIs that can be used for signaling the successful or unsuccessful completion, as well as the status of the task.` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q